# How to understand "Not feeling flash this morning, so I'm going to sit out"

Tags: meaning

> "Not feeling flash this morning, so I'm going to sit out"

This sentence is from an email of my colleague.

I understand it as "I'm sick this morning, so I won't work today", but not quite sure what the accuracy meaning of the two phrases:

1. "feel flash"
2. "sit out"

Is my understanding correct, and when to use them in daily life?

Comment: "Sit out" is a common idiom meaning "[not to participate](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/sit+out)" but "feel flash" is certainly not common in the US and I doubt it's common anywhere. I'd guess your interpretation is correct, though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a VERY, VERY common phrase used in British English, Australian and New Zealand English. It is also commonly misinterpreted by American English speakers.

To "feel flash" means to feel great, to be in good condition.
To "not feel flash" means to be in a bad condition.

In your example, the speaker isn't feeling too well.

Answer (score 1):

Is your email written by a non-native speaker? I have not come across any native speaker using 'feeling flash' till date.

But, if he is a non-native speaker...

he means he's not feeling ***energetic***. 'Flash' here is probably used to describe the energy within. I myself use it, though very rarely [The reason why I use is I think it's closely related to the ***'spark'***, the energy]. Mind it, it's **not** a standard usage.

It's **not** directly related but...I found an entry in the [WordWeb Dictionary](http://www.wordwebonline.com/en/FLASH):

> flash (noun, sense #1): *A sudden intense burst of radiant energy*

The friend is not feeling energetic and thus, as the comment describes, he's not taking part in whatsoever event/sport.

---

There are **rare chances** that a non-native speaker ***might*** have heard the usage of 'flush' and thus misunderstood it. The pronunciation of 'flash' and 'flush' is somewhat similar. This is because 'flush' is ***typically*** used to say that you are 'sick' (hot feeling as in fever). However, in such cases, in fact, you ***feel flush***.

Comment: http://onlineslangdictionary.com/meaning-definition-of/flash

Answer (score 0):

1) I think *feel flash* refers to flash lightning, or a lightning flash. The idea is that the person is usually full of spontaneous energy, usually electricity.

2) And *sit out* is kind of the opposite to *[stand up and be counted](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/stand+up+and+be+counted)* - if you don't agree with the motion, you wouldn't stand up, hence you would *sit it out*. Which basically means not participating.